# Is there an online / incremental / parallel version of t-SNE

Tags: machine-learning, tsne

Anyone know of one? I noticed the question was asked once before [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138319/are-there-any-versions-of-t-sne-for-streaming-data), without any answers.

Also I saw that contributors of scikit-learn are working on a more scalable version of t-SNE in a comment [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4619).